# Approximating a function sufficiently well so that they behave similarly

Tags: analysis, approximation

Given:

1. a continuous function $f:\Omega\to\Bbb{C}$ $(\Omega\subset\Bbb{C})$
2. $f = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$
3. a compact set $K\subset\Omega$
4. $a\in\Omega\setminus K$
5. $|f(a)| > \sup\limits_{K} |f|$

Then there exists $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $|f_N(a)| > \sup\limits_{K} |f_N|$

---

We can start be choosing a compact set $K_1$ containing $K$ and the point $a$. Now we have uniform approximation of $f$ on $K_1$ by $f_n$'s. Now to arrive at a contradiction we assume that no such $N$ exist. It is now possible to choose $N_1$ such that the inequality does not hold for $n>N_1$. Now I want to take the limit and arrive at a contradiction but I am not sure how to do that.

Am I in the right direction? Is there any other way to prove this which is easy to see?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a limit of a statement like this is going to be tricky because of the $\sup_K$.  Instead of trying to make sense of that, I would suggest directly using the definition of uniform convergence.  For any $\epsilon>0$, you can find $N$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in K_1$.  Writing $S=\sup_K |f|$, we in particular have $|f_n(x)|<|f(x)|+\epsilon\leq S+\epsilon$ for all $x\in K$, so $\sup_K |f_n(x)|\leq S+\epsilon$.  I'll let you now think about how to choose $\epsilon$ to be able to reach the desired conclusion.

Comment: Since $a\in K_1$, for any $\epsilon' >0$ there is a $N_1\in\Bbb{N}$ such that  $|f_n(a) - f(a)| <\epsilon'$ for $n>N_1$ or $|f(a)| < |f_n| + \epsilon'$. Now we have $\sup\limits_{K} |f_M(x)| < |f_M(a)| + \epsilon + \epsilon'$ where $M > max\{N,N_1\}$ and then we take limit $\epsilon\to 0$ and $\epsilon'\to 0$ both sides.

Comment: "Taking the limit" is problematic, because $M$ depends on $\epsilon$, and also it is not obvious how to take the limit of the left-hand side as $M\to\infty$.  As I said, I would recommend not trying to take any limits and just think about how to choose $\epsilon$ (and $\epsilon'$, though there is no real reason to distinguish $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon'$).